# C++: How to pass user input through the system without using global variables?

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

I am having the problem, that my application can has a lot of user input which determines how the application will be run. The application is an in memory database system and the user could for example invoke the program with commands like '--pagesize 16384' (sets the memory page size to use), '--alignment 4096' (sets the memory alignment to use) or '--measure' (sets a flag to measure certain routines).

Currently I save all the user input in global variables which are defined as extern in a header file:

```
//@file common.hh
extern  size_t      PAGE_SIZE_GLOBAL;
extern  size_t      ALIGNMENT_GLOBAL;
extern  size_t      MEMCHUNK_SIZE_GLOBAL;
extern  size_t      RUNS_GLOBAL;
extern  size_t      VECTORIZE_SIZE_GLOBAL;
extern  bool        MEASURE_GLOBAL;
extern  bool        PRINT_GLOBAL;
extern  const char* PATH_GLOBAL;
```

and in main source file:

```
#include "modes.hh"

size_t      PAGE_SIZE_GLOBAL;
size_t      ALIGNMENT_GLOBAL;
size_t      MEMCHUNK_SIZE_GLOBAL;
size_t      RUNS_GLOBAL;
size_t      VECTORIZE_SIZE_GLOBAL;
bool        MEASURE_GLOBAL;
bool        PRINT_GLOBAL;
const char* PATH_GLOBAL;

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]){

    ...
    //Initialize the globals with user input
    PAGE_SIZE_GLOBAL        = lArgs.pageSize();
    ALIGNMENT_GLOBAL        = lArgs.alignment();
    MEMCHUNK_SIZE_GLOBAL    = lArgs.chunkSize();
    RUNS_GLOBAL             = lArgs.runs();
    VECTORIZE_SIZE_GLOBAL   = lArgs.vectorized();
    MEASURE_GLOBAL          = lArgs.measure();
    PRINT_GLOBAL            = lArgs.print();
    std::string tmp         = lArgs.path() + storageModel + "/";
    PATH_GLOBAL             = tmp.c_str();

    ...
}
```

I then include the header file common.hh in each file, where a global variable is needed (which can be very deep down in the system).

I already read a dozen times to prevent global variables so this is obviously bad style. In the book 'Code Complete 2' from Steve McConnell the chapter about global variables also stated to prevent global variables and use access routines instead. In the section 'How to Use Access Routines' he writes

> "Hide data in a class. Declare that data by using the static keyword
>   (...) to ensure only a single instance of the data exists. Write
>   routines that let you look at the data and change it."

First of all, the global data won't change (maybe this is changed later but at least not in the near future). But I don't get how these access routines are any better? I will also have a class I need to include at every file where the data is needed. The only difference is the global data are static members accessed through getter functions.

(Edited) I also thought about using a global data Singleton class. But an object with ALL the global data sounds overkill since only a few global variables of the object are needed at its different destinations.

My Question: Should I just stick to the global variables? Are there better solutions, what am I missing? What are the best practices?

Edit:
If I would identify a few classes where the user input is needed the most, I could change the global data to member variables. What would be the best practice to pass the user input to these classes? Passing the data as parameters through the whole system down to the lowest layers sounds wrong. Is there are design pattern (thinking about something like a factory) which would be suited here?

Comment: Well if you use a singleton class you don't actually have to pass it around. Methods can do something like `Singleton::GetInstance()` which is a static method that returns a `Singleton&`. Ideally, though, in a OO solution your data and methods belong to the same class so there's little passing around involved.

Comment: I think the statement "only a few global variables of the object are needed at its different destinations" is a clue to your real problem. Having a set of global variables (or one class that exists just to be a bucket of global variables) means that your other classes end up with a dependency on the globals.

Your instinct that the singleton class full of globals isn't much better is basically right. That's just reorganizing the problem.

Think about giving each class just the minimum set of data it needs, even if this introduces some redundancy. Much easier to understand + test later.

Comment: @patatahooligan my bad, thanks. Even if I could find a class where the data is best suited at, how would I get the user input to this class?

Comment: @struthersneil How could I pass the user input (comming from main) to the different classes where the data is actually needed? Is there another way than passing the data as parameters through the whole system? I have different layers in my architecture and I can't go directly from main to the memory manger for example. The memory manager needs to know the used page size, alignment, etc..

Comment: Passing the data as parameters through the whole system isn't as bad as it sounds. I don't know exactly how you have set up your memory manager, but assuming your memory manager is an object that main instantiates at some point, I'd pass the necessary configuration into the constructor. Then you have a memory manager that is very easy to test in isolation under different configurations.

Comment: If we're still referring to a singleton, main will do something like `Singleton::get_instance().set_smth()` and then elsewhere you can write `Singleton::get_instance().get_smth()`, though I'm not a fan of this approach. I like writing wrapper classes for stuff I want to use and then just call methods of that class. What you're doing sounds like you have a functional set-up rather than an object-oriented one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to pass user input through the system without using global
>   variables.

It is easy.  Surprise, I created a class.

For a while, I called this class a travel case, because I considered it analogous to the needs of a suitcase during a trip. The TC_t is a non-standard container which held useful things for what is going on at your destination, and there is only one created, with references passed to any other objects that could use the information.  Not global, in the strictest sense.

This TC_t is created in main() thread, while studying the command line options.

---

I recently wrote yet-another-game-of-life.  User inputs included a) destination of output (i.e. a tty num), b) initial fill-pattern choices, c) 'overrides' for game board dimensions,  d) test modes, including max speed, and vector vs. array options for cell behaviours.

The GOLUtil_t (Game Of Life Utility) (previously TC_t) includes methods that are useful in more than one effort.

For your question, the two typical globals I avoided are the a) gameBoard, and b) ansi terminal access.

```
std::cout << "accessing '" << aTermPFN << "' with std::ofstream " 
          << std::endl;
std::ofstream*  ansiTerm = new std::ofstream(aTermPFN);

if (!ansiTerm->is_open())
{
   dtbAssert(nullptr != ansiTerm)(aTermPFN);
   std::cerr << "Can not access '" << aTermPFN << "'" << std::endl;
   assert(0);  // abort
 }

// create game-board - with a vector of cell*
CellVec_t  gameBoard;
gameBoard.reserve (aMaxRow * aMaxCol);

GOLUtil_t  gBrd(aMaxRow, aMaxCol, gameBoard, *ansiTerm);
```

This last line invoked the ctor of GOLUtil_t.

The instance "gBrd" is then passed (by reference) to the ctor of the game, and from there, to any aggregate objects it contained.

```
std::string retVal;
{
  // initialize display, initialize pattern
  GameOfLife_t  GOL(gBrd, timeOfDay, fillPatternChoiceLetter, useArray);

  std::string retValS = GOL.exec2(testMode);

  retVal = gBrd.clearGameBoard(retValS); // delete all cells
}
// force GameOfLife_t dtor before close ansiTerm

ansiTerm->close();
```

---

Summary - No globals.

Every instance of any class that needed this info (where to output? what are dimensions?) has access to the GOLUtil_t for their entire lifetime.  And GOLUtil_t has methods to lighten the coding load.

Note: because single output terminal, I used a single thread (main)

---

Your first refactor effort might be to:

a) remove the global classes,

b) and instead instantiate these in main() (for lifetime control)

c) and then pass-by-reference these formerly global instances to those non-global objects that make use of them. I recommend in the ctor(s).

d) remember to clean up (delete if new'd)

---

my environment:  Ubuntu 15.10, 64 bit,  g++ V5

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55697599/2785528 - my homework requires me to use booleans in my functions.  Do I need to pass them to the functions?