# Recursion without parameters, nor static or global variables

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I was given a homework that asked me to iterate through a linked list with a given class header which I should not change:

```
template<typename ItemType>
class LinkedList{
public: 
...
  LinkedList();
  LinkedList(const LinkedList<ItemType>&);
  int getCurrentSize340RecursiveNoHelper() const; 

private:
  Node<ItemType>* headPtr{ nullptr }; // Pointer to first node
}
```

The node class header is:

```
template<typename ItemType>
class Node {
public:
...
  Node();
  Node(const ItemType&);
  Node(const ItemType&, Node<ItemType>*);
  Node<ItemType>* getNext() const;

private:
  ItemType        item;          // A data item
  Node<ItemType>* next{ nullptr }; // Pointer to next node
}
```

In the function `getCurrentSize340RecursiveNoHelper()`, we are supposed to iterate the linked list to get the size.

I know that I could iterate the linked list with the help of static or global, but my professor says that we should avoid using them. Is there any possible way to do that?

Comment: What does the function have to do?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm guessing it has to just return the size of the linked list? `getCurrentSize340RecursiveNoHelper`

Comment: To get the size of the linked list by recursion.

Comment: Here's a hint: The size of a linked list is 1+ the size of the linked list with the head at the next element

Comment: How can you check if the list has 0 elements? One?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It would help if you also provided the full declaration of the class member variabls.

Comment: @TedBrownlow Ya, but how could I move the pointer from the head to the next node?

Comment: Well, you need to store state *somewhere*. If statics and globals are out, then how about a non-static member? It's an odd thing to do, but then you are given a very odd task to solve.

Comment: Is `getCurrentSize340RecursiveNoHelper` a member function?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, it is a member function in a linked list class

Comment: Are there no constructors?

Comment: @Michael There are. The linked list and the node is complete. I am just adding function to the linked list.

Comment: @AppleBS could you also add the headers for the constructors, then the problem is fully solvable

Comment: @Michael The headers are added.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. Technically, none of the headers that you have provided allow for any way to actually set the `headPtr` member of a `LinkedList` object. I assumed the constructors would have been the way to do that, but it looks like they aren't.How do you actually set the `headPtr`?

Comment: @Michael  The constructor only initialized ````headPtr```` to nullptr. The ````headPtr```` would only be pointed to a node if an object is added. There is no way to set ````headPtr```` unless I am calling a ````remove```` function or some sort.

Comment: @AppleBS Okay, IMO I feel like being able to pass a pointer through a constructor to set the `headPtr` would be the most intuitive. From what I understand, though, you can use `add` to set the `headPtr`? I updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: Why does this have to be recursion? Is that part of the assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the function getCurrentSize340RecursiveNoHelper(), we are supposed
>   to iterate the linked list to get the size.
>
> I know that I could iterate the linked list with the help of static or
>   global, but my professor says that we should avoid using them.
>
> Is there any possible way to do that?

Last question first: YES, this is possible, even easy. Software is remarkably flexible.

> Recursion without function parameters (nor static vars, nor global vars).

Iteration and recursion *without parameters* are both easy to do, once you've seen how.

And with practice, you can easily avoid both static and global vars.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45550373/2785528, which presents a simple mechanism to "pass user input through a system without using global vars".  We might summarize it into 2 steps, a) early in main instantiate a custom class instance to contain (for 'transport') any user inputs / values that you would otherwise place into global vars for the various users to fetch, and then b) pass these transport objects by reference to the ctors of objects that need them (in similar fashion to a travel case).  Easy.

---

Kudo's to the professor to insist on user-defined-types (UDT).  This is the stuff you need to practice on.

However, for this post, it will be simpler to study the how-to (of iteration and recursion without parameters, etc.) by simply ignoring the UDT with which you stated no problems.  In this way, we can concentrate on the function forms.

To simplify even more, my examples will be Functors ... a short and simple form of classes.  I recommend Functor classes as both simple and efficient.

And one more simplification, I will use std::list. There are plenty of examples of how to make, fill, and use this container.

One key idea (to support no-parameter-functions) is to 'bundle' your data and methods into the class.  Encapsulation is your friend.

---

Idea 1 -- Minimize main().  Keep it short.  Get out and direct to business.

```
int main(int, char**)
{
   int retVal = 0;
   retVal    += F820_Iterative_t()();
   retVal    += F820_Recursive_t()();
   return retVal;
}
```

Here, two functors are invoked.  I separated the iterative from recursive examples.

Note that these functors are invoked early in main.  There are many things that get initialized before main (but see the well known initialization fiasco).  This simplifies and controls when these init's happen.

The first functor will instantiate, process, then destruct, completing its full lifetime before the next functor gets started, i.e. they are serialized.

---

data types:

```
// examples use std::list
// user typedefs ---------------vvvvvvvvvvv
typedef list<string>            StrList_t;
typedef list<string>::iterator  StrListIt_t;
```

data attributes:

```
// Functor
class F820_Iterative_t
{
   // NOTE: class instance data attributes are not global vars
   StrList_t    m_strList; // std::list<std::string>
   StrListIt_t  m_it;      // std::list<std::string>::iterator
   ...


// Functor
class F820_Recursive_t
{
   StrList_t    m_strList; // std::list<std::string>
   StrListIt_t  m_it;      // std::list<std::string>::iterator
   ...
```

---

Example 1 -- iterative element count

```
// iterate with no parameters, static vars, or global vars
uint F820_Iterative_t::iterateCount( )
   {                           // --^-- no params
      uint lcount = 0;
      do // -------------iterative loop
      {
         if (m_it == m_strList.end()) // detect end of list
            break;                    // kick out

         lcount += 1;

         m_it++;                   // step to next element

      } while(true);

      return(lcount);
   }
```

Example 2 -- recursive element count

```
// recurse with no parameters, static vars, or global vars
uint F820_Recursion_t::recurseCount( )
   {                           // --^-- no params
    if (m_it == m_strList.end()) // RTC (recursion termination clause)
        return 0;

    m_it++; // step to next element

    return (1 + recurseCount());   // tail recursion
} //          --^^^^^^^^^^^^-- recursive invocation
```

In both of the above element count functions, the Functor data attributes are initialized before F820_xxx::xxxCount() is invoked.

This code uses no function parameters, and no global vars.  The vars used in these funcs (m_it and m_strList) are data attributes of the class instance.  The function access them directly through the implied 'this' pointer.

---

Life interrupts.

Both xxxxCount() are above for comparison.  Ask for more if you want, this code compiles and runs.  I plan to find time to insert the rest.

Answer (score 4):

You can recurse through member variables rather than parameters.

```
int LinkedList::getCurrentSize340RecursiveNoHelper() const {
    if (this->headPtr == nullptr){
        return 0;
    }

    Node<ItemType> nextNode = this->headPtr->getNext();
    if (nextNode != nullptr){
        LinkedList<ItemType> restOfList;
        restOfList.add(nextNode); // a bit weird but this is the only way you can set the headPtr of a linked list.
        return 1 + restOfList.getCurrentSize340RecursiveNoHelper();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the base case.

Comment: @0x499602D2 updated. I think this particular function gurantees a size of at least 1, however. This is because since it's a member function, if you called this on a node that wasn't null, it implies that the list has at least one element in the linked list - itself.

Comment: That's true unless it's acting as a sentinel node.

Comment: Also be aware you can recurse all the way to StackOverflow on large lists.

Answer (score 1):

When you're dealing with recursive problems, a trick is to just assume that the recursive function works if and only if you give it a simpler problem to work on than the one you're dealing with. You're given a pointer to the head of the linked list. After you've dealt with the base case, you now know that the list has *at least* one element. A simpler problem you can ask your recusive function to do is to calculate the length of the *rest* of the list and then just add 1 to the result.